# Flask - how to differentiate ID of cloned elements in HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

As part of a personal project, I'm trying implement a version of this website https://www.steroidplotter.com/, using `Python Flask`. I've been somewhat successful but there are some finer details I'm struggling with. Here's what my version looks like so far: [progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAVut.png). I am struggling with how to differentiate the different elements that have been cloned in.

Here's my html code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
        function cb(selection) {
            $.getJSON({
                url: "/callback", data: {
                    'data': selection,
                    'selected_compound': $('#compounds_list').val(),
                    'selected_form': $('#compound_forms').val(),
                    'dosage': $('#dose').val(),
                    'weeks_dose_start': $('#weeks_dose_start').val()
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    Plotly.newPlot('chart', result, { staticPlot: true });;
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#compounds_list').change(function () {
                $.getJSON('/_update_dropdown', {
                    selected_compound: $('#compounds_list').val()
                }).success(function (data) {
                    $('#compound_forms').html(data.html_string_selected);
                })
            });

            $('#add_compound_button').click(function () {
                console.log('test ' + $('#compounds_list').attr('id'));
                $('.single-compound-div:last').clone().insertAfter('.single-compound-div:last');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body style="font-family:arial, sans-serif">
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <div id="all-compounds-div">
        <div class="single-compound-div">
            <div class="row compound-row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                    <label for="compounds_list">Select a compound</label>
                    <select class="form-control compound" style="color: white; background: #34568B;" id="compounds_list">
                        {% for o in compounds_list %}
                        <option value="{{ o }}">{{ o }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                    <label for="compound_forms">Select an ester or form</label>
                    <select class="form-control form" style="color:white; background:#009B77;" id="compound_forms">
                        {% for o in compound_forms %}
                        <option value="{{ o }}">{{ o }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                    <label for="dose">Input dosage (mg)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dose" name="dose">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                    <label for="weeks_dose_start"> Start week </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="weeks_dose_start" name="weeks_dose_start">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                    <label for="weeks_dose_end"> End week </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="weeks_dose_end" name="weeks_dose_end" value="1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div> <button id="add_compound_button" type="button" class="btn btn-dark"> Add new compound </button> </div>
    <div> <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="cb()"> Plot </button> </div>
    <div id="chart" class="chart"></div>
</body>

<script>
    d = {{ graphJSON | safe }};
    //d.config={staticPlot: true};
    Plotly.newPlot('chart', d, {});

</script>

</html>
```

I know I need to update `$('#compounds_list')` but I'm not sure how. I also can't figure out how to update the second dropdown in each row. Again, because of the ID, all second dropdowns refer to the value in the first row's selection. Lastly, I'll need to update the following block so that all values of the same type are sent as arrays (e.g. the values in each of the dosage text boxes should be sent together).

```
data: {
                    'data': selection,
                    'selected_compound': $('#compounds_list').val(),
                    'selected_form': $('#compound_forms').val(),
                    'dosage': $('#dose').val(),
                    'weeks_dose_start': $('#weeks_dose_start').val()
                }
```

The python code referenced for the dropdown update:

```
def update_dropdown():
    # the value of the first dropdown (selected by the user)
    selected_compound = request.args.get('selected_compound', type=str)
    
    # get values for the second dropdown
    updated_values = get_dropdown_values()[selected_compound]
    
    # create the value sin the dropdown as a html string
    html_string_selected = ''
    for entry in updated_values:
        html_string_selected += '<option value="{}">{}</option>'.format(entry, entry)

    return jsonify(html_string_selected=html_string_selected)
```

I've been following the examples here: https://alanjones2.github.io/Flask-Plotly/.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. First off, I see you are loading two versions of jQuery: 3.5.1 and then 1.12.4. You will want to to sort that out first as it will create many unforseen issues.

Comment: Nest each `<input />` element inside its `<label></label>` element then remove the ids and the `for` attributes. Unless the ids are required for some other purpose, everything will work fine.